# Is there an Intel Graphics Update Tool for Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: intel-graphics, 17.04

The latest version I could find is [V2.0.4](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.4) which dates back to 16 Feb, 2017.

Does that mean that 17.04 already has the latest Intel graphics drivers built into the distribution?

Comment: Have you checked the [17.04 release note](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an Intel Graphics Update Tool for Ubuntu 17.04?

Yes. There is an [Intel Graphics Update Tool v2.0.5](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.5) that works on Ubuntu 17.04, but it is not included in the distribution. You must download the software from the Intel Technology Center.

There are two packages that you can use depending if you use a 64-bits or 32-bits installation.

- [amd64.deb](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.5_amd64.deb)
- [i386.deb](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.5_i386.deb)

Comment: here's a link to all the downloads: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool

Answer (score 4):

As of 4/18, "The next release of the update tool is being prepared, and should go to testing in a couple of weeks."

Probably more importantly, "This update for Ubuntu 17.04 will be quite small, since the distro released shortly after the 01.org stack
was announced - just VAAPI video acceleration and cairo (2D userspace graphics library) will be included
(since everything else is already up to date)."

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-update-tool-discussions/instructions-compiling-and-installing-update-tool-ubuntu-17

Comment: Can you please provide the link here once it had been released?

Comment: So, any news yet?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an Intel Graphics Update Tool for Ubuntu 17.04?

No. Not until now. But they may release one soon since 17.04 is only released this April, 13. That tool is 3rd party so not for Ubuntu/Canonical to maintain.

The way this driver works: they only support the last released version and the LTS. From the link:

> Ubuntu* 16.10 was released in October 2016. All support for Ubuntu* 16.04 will end when Ubuntu* 17.04 is released, currently scheduled in April 2017.

and

> Does that mean that 17.04 already has the latest Intel graphics drivers built into the distribution?

It doesn't say anything about the status of Intel drivers in default 17.04. But it *does say* one thing and that is they need to update their website and/or maybe the driver stacks too ;)

Comment: Most importantly, their tools maybe

Comment: That maybe true, But I'm using an obsolete graphics (onboard) card and it seems they still have something for me :)